# PDO insert query failing

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

PHP:

```
    if(strcasecmp($refId, 'guest') == 0)
    {
        if(strcasecmp( $amount, '24.95' ) == 0)
        {
                $credits = 20;
                $plan = 'cool';     
        }
        if(strcasecmp( $amount, '45.95' ) == 0)
        {
            $credits = 40;
            $plan = 'awesome';
        }
        if(strcasecmp( $amount, '69.95' ) == 0)
        {
            $credits = 60;
            $plan = 'Supreme';
        }

            $keyy = generate_key_string();
            $query = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO keys (keys_key, keys_plan, keys_credit) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"); 
            $query->bindValue(1, $keyy);
            $query->bindValue(2, $plan);
            $query->bindValue(3, $credits);
            if(!$query->execute())
            {
                echo 'failed' . '<br/>';
                echo $plan . '<br/>';
                echo $keyy . '<br/>';
                echo $credits;

            }           
    }
```

SQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE `keys` (
  `keys_key` varchar(29) NOT NULL,
  `keys_credits` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `keys_plan` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`keys_key`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I know the values are there because that's my output

```
failed
cool
CDGSI-DUEXP-M9BUZ-4VMQA-YSLIU
20
```

the query doesn't seem to be working for just this insert, I have different insert functions on other pages and they work fine. Thanks

Comment: Try adding a `var_dump($query->ErrorInfo())` to see what error the query is generating.

Comment: `array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "42000" [1]=> int(1064) [2]=> string(226) "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'keys (keys_key, keys_plan, keys_credit) VALUES ('B1VN9-GVPQ1-RT9X3-0BHBU-I2PIU',' at line 1" }` should the varchar for keys_key be just text?

Comment: See echo_me's answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`keys` is [reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html) you should escape your columns and tables if you use reserved keywords  by backticks

like that

```
    INSERT INTO `keys`
```

Comment: I don't know why you got downvoted. You might want to add a suggestion to avoid using reserved words as column or table names, but that's the only improvement I can think of.

Comment: Thank you, I was worrying about keywords at first when I named the table `key` but I thought that was going to be a keyword so I named it `keys` in the future I'll be sure to use backticks or naming them something different! Thanks!

Comment: you welcome :) , i have posted link to reserved keywords so you can check when you use them :) , good luck with your code